# Is there a way to specify UTF8 encdoing or add the bom character when transforming one CSV file to another in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, byte-order-mark, node-csv-parse

I'm using the csv module along with csv-parse, stream-transform and csv-stringify modules to read in an excel file and select the columns I need. The CSV file contains special characters in Portuguese that cannot be encoded properly because I ignore the BOM character so that I can get the correct column names. I wanted to know if there was a way to add the BOM character to the resulting file so that the file can be properly encoded? Here are the options I use for the parser:

```
parse({
    columns:true,
    delimeter: ',', 
    bom: true
})
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a transform stream that adds a BOM at the start? Or are you saying the first row has a different endianness than the rest?

Comment: @DavidKnipe the former.

Comment: Problem solved. If anyone else is having the same issue you can do `fs.writeFile(filename, '\ufeff', callback());` to write the bom character and then when you create your writeStream `fs.createWriteStream(filename, {flag: 'a'});` Then you can use `pipe()` as normal.

Comment: You're calling `callback` synchronously, before you ever write to the stream. You meant `callback`, not `callback()`. If you call the callback function before calling `fs.writeFile` then there's no guarantee that the BOM will be at the start. Or as the documentation says: "It is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile()` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback." https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback